# How do I display tuples in columns? [Python]

Tags: python, output, tuples

I would like to know how to display a tuple in a column format in python. Let's say that these are my tuples:

```
name = ("Adam", "Chris", "Geoff", "Jack", "Kevin", "Nick",)  
sport = ("Baseball", "Football", "Cricket", "Soccer", "Volleyball", "Hockey",)
age = ("12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17",)
```

and I want them to display like this:

```
Name:          Sport:          Age:
Adam           Baseball        12
Chris          Football        13
Geoff          Cricket         14
Jack           Soccer          15
Kevin          Volleyball      16
Nick           Hockey          17
```

What would I have to do? Any and all help would be appreciated. Thank you for reading.

Comment: looks like homework?? hun

Comment: haha, agree with Hackaholic, looks like homework. and actually the name, sport, age are 1-to-1. So u might consider loop through them at the same time

Comment: yeah... programming 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this, use `ljust`

```
>>> for i in range(len(name)):
...     print(name[i].ljust(20,' '),sport[i].ljust(20,' '),age[i].ljust(20,' '))
... 
Adam                 Baseball             12                  
Chris                Football             13                  
Geoff                Cricket              14                  
Jack                 Soccer               15                  
Kevin                Volleyball           16                  
Nick                 Hockey               17
```

before for put this:

```
print("Name:".ljust(20,' '),"Sport:".ljust(20,' '),"Age:".ljust(20,' '))
```

you can also use `format`:

```
>>> for i in range(len(name)):
...     print("{0:<20}{1:<20}{2:<20}".format(name[i],sport[i],age[i]))
... 
Adam                Baseball            12                  
Chris               Football            13                  
Geoff               Cricket             14                  
Jack                Soccer              15                  
Kevin               Volleyball          16                  
Nick                Hockey              17
```